# make public api readonly, but internally read/write?

Tags: objective-c

How do I do this:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (readonly) int bar;
@end

...

@interface Foo()
@property (nonatomic) int bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar = _bar;
   // stuff that does self.bar = 123;
@end
```

so that some external class cannot call foo.bar = 123..  but internal methods inside Foo can... ?

Answer (score 4):

Adding `readwrite` to `nonatomic` in the class extension should do it:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int bar;
```